# SDL Web 8.5 - legacy API (in-process) Server Role for a .NET Web application is not working

Tags: web8.5

I have a problem using the legacy API in-process for a .Net Web application. I have installed these APIs following the steps of the **[manual](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-41262406-9599-4FFE-9563-E9F8CB9FC302#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-D5BA53C0-C43B-45E7-A8BF-8A7BE48C3B0A.xml&docid=GUID-0D330E1A-A753-45D2-B462-3121F756EE14&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-0D330E1A-A753-45D2-B462-3121F756EE14&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL+Web-v5%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dlegacy%2520api&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1561460112582&currentQuery=legacy%2520api&currentScope=)**. When I launch a test of this APIs, the links are not resolved and nothing is written in any log (although we have correctly configured the `logback.xml` inside the `/bin/config/` folder of the .Net application).
The code of our test is:

[image]

This code causes an exception because link1 is `null`. 
The ids in the variables are correct and refer to existing and published elements.
What can be happening? How can we configure or view a log with the details?

Comment: How does your `cd_link_conf.xml` look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the configuration of the database in cd_storage_conf.xml. Once the data is entered correctly, it works without problems.